# Vue + Laravel: String is getting stripped when passed as a prop in blade file

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a blade file with the following:

```
$customerId = time() . rand(0, 100000) . '-' . $redItem->id;

<Flashbar
     :user-ref={!! json_encode($customerId) !!}
/>
```

My issue is that the Flashbar component is setup to take a userRef as a prop with the type of String but it's stripping everything after the `time() . rand(0, 100000)` ...it's not including the `-` and the redItem->id afterwards.
I've been inspecting the props with the Vue devtools on Flashbar and it;'s just the time and random number.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment below, I think this might be happening because vue is interpreting your `$customerId` as an equation.

```php
$customerId = time() . rand(0, 100000) . '-' . $redItem->id;
```

If the `$redItem`'s id was 1, this would generate someting like: `155743641671228-1`

However, when you v-bind a prop (you're using the : shorthand to do so), any input provided to it will first be interpreted by javascript. So what you're seeing when you inspect your prop is the sum of: 155743641671228 - 1 (155743641671227).

Therefore, if you replace the '-' with something that isn't a javascript operator when you generate your customer id - it should work.

For example:

```php
$customerId = time() . rand(0, 100000) . ':' . $redItem->id;
```

I would have thought that removing the v-bind would also cause this to work, but I may be wrong...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Might actually be because the input is numeric, javascript is subtracting the id from the generated timestamp and random number. I.e (155743641671228-1 = 155743641671227). Try changing the '-' for a ':'. Would have thought that removing the v-bind from the prop would have fixed that though!

Answer (score 0):

This is a string, there is no need to json encode it. nor is there a reason to bind it as its not a variable from the vue instance.

```
<Flashbar user-ref="{{ $customerId }}" />
```